# raycast returns null when colliding with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to catch game object using raycast and hit data structure 
1)I have one nested object containing 2 other objects image and text UI 
2) I added collider to the parent game object 
3) I gave the parent object mask layer to give to raycaster when detecting collisions

the problem is:
I keep getting null value from physics.raycast when clicking on the object
I also tried raycast2dhit and got the same result   
her is my code :

```html
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("mouse clicked");
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Infinity,(1<<6))){
            Debug.Log(hit.collider);
        }
     
     }
 }
```

any idea what is causing this issue I'm stuck at this for 2 days and I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: Is it 2d or 3d. If its 2d you need different methods

Comment: if your target objects are UI you should rather be using the [`GraphicsRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) ... you will find it attached to your `Canvas` by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a few questions and a few ideas:

First is: is the hit really null? If it is then you should be getting a nullreferenceexception. As far as I know this *should* be impossible, as the point of the out statement is to prevent use of the potentially null RaycastHit.

Second is: Removing the RaycastHit variable declaration and using `out var hit` instead.

```
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out var hit,Mathf.Infinity,(1<<6))){
            Debug.Log(hit.collider);
        }
```

The goal of this is to ensure that the hit is always set to a value.

Third is: Check your layermask! I don't know your layer list in unity, but I'd recommend making a public LayerMask variable which you pass as the layer argument to the raycast. Also check the layer of the object you are trying to hit with the ray. The idea here is to ensure that the layer you think you checking are in fact the right ones.

Without any more info thats all I can say, hope it helps. (Also using any 2D physics functions only applies if you're using a 2D project).

Comment: the out var hit fixed the issue like magic thanks a lot i was getting crazy because of this but what is the difrence between declaring with var and declaring with raycatehit

Comment: @karam
Im not actually entirely sure, I won't lie to you. In theory your debug line should never get called unless hit is assigned, I doubt its a bug in Unity's code but you could submit a bug report. If you want to make it clearer for yourself too, you could replace `var` with `RaycastHit` and it should be functionally identical.